# select list is not in group by clause and contains nonaggregated column laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

```
$all_ps = Palletstock::where('status', 0)
         ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('palletpart', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        $query->orwhere('location', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        $query->orWhere('supplier_code', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        $query->orWhere('qty', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        }) ->offset($start)->limit($length)->
        groupBy('palletpart','location','supplier_code', 'qty' )->get();
```

After using groupBy, i got the same error 'select list is not in group by clause and contains nonaggregated column'.

Answer (score 0):

You have an SQL query with grouping but you selecting all columns without grouping aggregation.
It's like you have a query:

```
SELECT palletpart, location, supplier_code, qty, OTHER_COLUMN
FROM palletstock
GROUP BY palletpart, location, supplier_code, qty
```

Then the last OTHER_COLUMN must be some aggregated function like SUM(), COUNT(), AVG() i.e.

```
SELECT palletpart, location, supplier_code, qty, SUM(OTHER_COLUMN)
FROM palletstock
GROUP BY palletpart, location, supplier_code, qty
```